# PHP usort comparator function needs access to class member variables - how to call it

Tags: php

I am trying to use the `usort()` function in PHP. I am not sure how to call the comparison function. Here is my code below. I tried `$this->comparator` and that didnt help. This would have been easy if `comparator` was a function that didn't need to access the class's member variables.

```
class A { 
   $p1    // non-associative array 
   $p2    // non-associative array
   public function comparator($a, $b)
   {
       // the usual comparison stuff
       if ($this->p1[$a] == $this->p2[$b])
            return 0; 
       else ($this->p1[$a] < $this->p2[$b])
            return 1; 
       else
            return -1;
   }

   public function sorting()
   {
      // after some code
      $some_array = array(..); 
      usort($some_array, "comparator")    // <--- ERROR here: does not recognize comparator
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the sort function in a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) way:

```
usort($some_array, array($this, "comparator"));
```

Even though the type callable didn't exist prior to PHP 5.4, referencing methods works the same way.